# how change location (latitude and longitude) from new update of emulator:Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, updates

in new update : There is no "more" button to change location of emulator

like this image :

[image: no more "..." button]

how to change location like old version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new Emulator Tool Window still misses many features from the original Emulator window.

Such as Mutli Touch Gestures, settings dialog, etc.

If you need these features, stick to the old Emulator Window instead.